# Older sets in The Lego Movie?

Tags: the-lego-movie

Are there any existing/hisorical complete sets (for example: buildings, vehicles, etc) featured in The Lego Movie? Sets [created specifically for the movie](http://www.lego.com/en-us/movie/products/products/70800-getaway-glider) do not count. For example, the bad cop's grandparent's house looks awfully familiar but I couldn't place whether that is an exact set that already exists, or just in the style of some of the older vacation/holiday house sets.

Answer (score 8):

> The Toa Mata from BIONICLE briefly appear in the film when Wyldstyle
>   is talking to Emmet about the prophecy. So do Fabuland, 9448 Samurai
>   Mech from Ninjago, 3189 Heartlake Stables from Friends, 8158 Speed
>   Racer & Snake Oiler from Speed Racer, along with a few other themes.
>   Some stopmotion videos created by fans on ReBrick were featured in the
>   movie.

[Brickipedia: The LEGO Movie](http://www.lego.wikia.com/wiki/The_LEGO_Movie)

The car Emmet drives at the beginning of the movie is a slightly modified version of the [3177 Small Car](http://brickset.com/sets/3177-1/Small-Car).

Answer (score 7):

Yes! Well, it depends... When you say featured, do you mean "it appears in the movie" or "it plays a central role in the movie"? If the former, many of them appear in "real life" scenes of the basement.

One of my [favorite sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=6339-1) from my childhood was in one of the [background dioramas](https://imgur.com/DhJJfWW). I got to see the complete basement movie set at LEGOLand California last week. They filled the film with old sets.

Comment: Appears in the movie as background scenery could count :)

Comment: FYI, [6339](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/6339_Shuttle_Launch_Pad) also appeared in Stargate SG-1 season 1 episode [Cold Lazarus](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s1/106.shtml). You can see it in [this screencap](http://www.gateworld.net/gallery/displayimage.php?album=17&pid=150702#top_display_media).